# Re-implement a QuTip function without the need for the QuTip toolbox

Tags: python, function, quantum-computing, qutip

Is there a way to implement this function that is part of QuTip functions (
Quantum Toolbox in Python) without the need for installing QuTip?

```
def destroy(N, offset=0):
    if not isinstance(N, (int, np.integer)):  # raise error if N not integer
        raise ValueError("Hilbert space dimension must be integer value")
    data = np.sqrt(np.arange(offset+1, N+offset, dtype=complex))
    ind = np.arange(1,N, dtype=np.int32)
    ptr = np.arange(N+1, dtype=np.int32)
    ptr[-1] = N-1
    return Qobj(fast_csr_matrix((data,ind,ptr),shape=(N,N)), isherm=False)
```

DESTROY returns annihilation operator for N-dimensional Hilbert space
out = destroy(N), N is integer value &  N>0